# Check is_null for list of field in Django queryset filtering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have create model with this fields:

```
field_1 , field_2, field_3, ... , field_n
```

And I want to `filter` all objects that these k fields:

```
field_1 , field_2, .... , field_k
```

of those objects is n't `Null`.

**My wrong answer:**

I did think that I must create this list of fields that I want to set in my query:

```
my_list = [`field_1` , `field_2`, .... , `field_k`]
```

and create my query like this:

```
my_objects = Class.objects.filter([ (eval(field_name +"__isnull = False") )  for field_name in my_list ])
```

But it was wrong. ***How can I do that?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make things too complicated, you can not construct a list with strings and pass it to `filter(..)` in the hope that it will work. Furthermore `eval(..)` does not work that way, and even if it did, it would result in severe security risks. `eval(..)` and `exec(..)` should be avoided as much as possible, since from the moment someone manages to "inject" a string into it, they can run arbitrary code on your server, and thus try to "dump the database", etc. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) for a more in-depth analysis on why "*Eval is bad practice*".

You can construct a list of fields names (so strings):

```
my_list = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_k']
```

Then we can construct a dictionary and perform dictionary unpacking, like:

```
Class.objects.filter(**{'{}__isnull'.format(f): False for f in my_list})
```

The two asterisks (`**`), will thus make a function call, such that `f(**{'a': 4, 'b': 2})`, is the same as `f(a=4, b=2)`, and thus here it will make a call like `.filter(field_1__isnull=False, field_2__isnull=False, field_k__isnull=False)`.

Or since [python-3.6](/questions/tagged/python-3.6), we can make use of *f-strings*:

```
Class.objects.filter(**{f'{f}__isnull': False for f in my_list})
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I have question about `eval`: If I don't get the value that pass to `eval` function from the user and fill it in myself, is there still a security problem? @willem-van-onsem

Comment: @Whale52Hz: it is a function that, imho, only can come from hell :). It is simply inelegant, nearly all you do with it can be done in a better way than with eval, it is inefficient, and furthermore it is "complicated" in the sense that passing variables to the `eval` might often be harder than one expects :).

Comment: :) Nice. OK thanks. I try to forget that python have such a function :) @willem-van-onsem