# Get value of related object by list of fields in @property

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models

I have two model like this with following fields:

```
Profile: 
    -user(OTO Relation to User)
    -address(OTO to Address)
    -bio
    -gender
    ...
Address: 
    -postal_code
    -phone_number
    -zip_code
```

I Also I have this list of fields name:

```
 my_list = ["bio","gender","address.postal_code","address.phone_number", "address.zip_code"]
```

And finally I want to I create this `@property`:

```
@property
def is_complete_profile(self):
    ''' Checks if all the fields have been filled '''
    if self.pk:
        for field_name in my_list:
            value = getattr(self,field_name)
            if not value:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But for `related objects` this isn't the correct way and I got this error:

> 'Profile' object has no attribute 'address.postal_code'

***How Can I use this list for get value of field of `Profile` objects and related object values?***

***Notice:***

> I could solve this problem by using `eval` function, but because of
>   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841701/check-is-null-for-list-of-field-in-django-queryset-filtering) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) post, I preferred to throw this solution away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having `Profile` nose around in its peers' internals, I would give each class involved an `is_complete` property (or method) which determines if the instance is complete, and have `Profile.is_complete_profile` access those properties to determine if the profile is totally complete.

Something like this (untested)

```
class Address:

    def is_complete(self):
        fields = ["postal_code", "phone_number", "zip_code"]
        for field in fields:
            if not getattr(self, field):
                return False
        return True

class Profile:

    def is_complete(self):
        fields = ["bio","gender"]
        for field in fields:
            if not getattr(self, field):
                return False
        return True

    @property
    def is_complete_profile(self):
        ''' Checks if all the fields have been filled '''
        if self.pk:
            return self.is_complete() and self.address.is_complete()
        return False
```

This way `Profile` doesn't need to change if the names of `Address`'s fields change, and only minimal changes are required if additional objects get added to the notion of "completeness".

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your `Profile` object **really** does not have an `address.postal_code` attribute. It has **address** attribute and that `address` has an `postal_code` attribute.

You can accomplish this with a simple **trick**:

```
@property
def is_complete_profile(self):
    ''' Checks if all the fields have been filled '''
    if self.pk:
        for field_name in my_list:
            if '.' in field_name:
                value = getattr(getattr(self, field_name.split('.')[0]), field_name.split('.')[1])
            else:
                value = getattr(self,field_name)
            if not value:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Nice answer @pedram-parsian . I did vote to your answer. But I think that  answer of  snakecharmerb is more better.Excuse me for not being able to accept both answers.